# Rails/ActiveRecord - How can I make this more concise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my view I have a line such as the following:

```
<%= @house.person.phone_number unless @house.person.nil?  %>
```

It seems like I have to do this sort of thing a lot as some fields are nullable.

Is there a better way to write this?

I could handle it at the model layer but thats not really model layer functionality, as I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@house.person.try(:phone_number)`

Comment: Beat me to it.. Although I also support Dave's answer to some extent.

Comment: Law of Demeter is great, but Dave's answer doesn't solve the problem if @person is nil.

Comment: I like your `.try` approach but there are two things: 1. it fails silently if the person model has no `phone_number` attribute/method at all, so debugging gets tricky. 2. `.try` is only supported by newer versions of ruby

Comment: @sled `#try` is monkey patched by rails http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try. Response to your #1, the OP is using it in a view so debugging won't be an issue.

Comment: @sled `#try` will not fail silently for undefined methods on an object other than an instance of NilClass.

Comment: I think I support my answer below more because it combines the goodness of Dave's answer (Law of demeter) and goodness of "try" method. Plus it's more concise too. Thoughts?

Comment: @Beerlington But I bet the OP could figure out how to extend it so it does.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [delegate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) method supported by active record.

`delegate :phone_number, :to => :person, :allow_nil => true`

And call `@house.phone_number` directly, avoiding the `person` middleman too. If phone is nil, this will also return nil.

Comment: +1 - Never knew about the all_nil option. I would personally go with this over my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

These [Strongly-Worded Suggestion of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)-type issues can certainly be wrapped up in the model by wrapping up the `Person`'s methods in the `House`, exposing less information in the process.

```
def person_phone_number
    @person.phone_number || ""
end
```

Kind of clunky; you could also meta-program them in to place.

Or create helpers, or a combo of both. This is a typical issue, and IMO there's nothing wrong with wrapping it up in the containing model.